# getting error when instaling adobe media server 5.0.3 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, server, adobe, media

I am getting following error when running following script.

```
sudo bash ./installAMS

./installAMS: line 289: ./amsini: Permission denied
 ERROR: The older Linux version Debian is detected and not supported
       by the Adobe Media Server installer.
       Please upgrade OS to the latest version.
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

There is a discuss on this topic [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5017583).

First remove the existing libcap installation:

```
sudo dpkg -r libcap2:amd64
```

Download older libcap:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2_2.17-2 ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Install libcap:

```
sudo dpkg -i libcap2_2.17-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Download libnspr4 library:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nspr/libnspr4_4.8.9-1ubu ntu3_amd64.deb
```

Install libnspr:

```
sudo dpkg -i libnspr4_4.8.9-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Edit the installAMS and replace `exit_no_libcap` with `exit_no_libcap-dev` and `exit_wrong_libcap` with `exit_wrong_libcap-dev`.

Comment: Just me or the links are cut off?

Comment: I get a scrollbar below the link, so I can select the full URL.

Comment: No I mean in the wget's, at the end reads `libcap2_2.17-2 ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb` and `libnspr4_4.8.9-1ubu ntu3_amd64.deb`